# php curl gives different result than from command line

Tags: php, curl

I am working on downloading ZIP from URL, and I have a problem with this. First step of my algorithm is to check what is the `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` of given url:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.dropbox.com/s/0hvgw7nvbdnh13d/ColaClassic.zip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); //I
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); //without body
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); //L
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_exec($ch);
$content_type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
```

However, value of variable `$content-type` is `text/html; charset=utf-8`

Then I checked `Content-Type` from command line like this:

```
curl -IL https://www.dropbox.com/s/0hvgw7nvbdnh13d/ColaClassic.zip
```

and I got correct result (`application/zip`).

So, what is the difference between these two codes, and how do I get correct `Content-Type` in my php script?

Edit:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/0hvgw7nvbdnh13d/ColaClassic.zip');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'HEAD');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
```

Verbose output from php curl:

```
* Hostname was found in DNS cache
* Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped
*   Trying 162.125.69.1...
* Connected to www.dropbox.com (162.125.69.1) port 443 (#14)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*    subject: businessCategory=Private Organization; 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US; 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware; serialNumber=4348296; C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=Dropbox, Inc; CN=www.dropbox.com
*    start date: 2017-11-14 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2020-02-11 12:00:00 GMT
*    subjectAltName: www.dropbox.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> HEAD /s/0hvgw7nvbdnh13d/ColaClassic.zip HTTP/1.1
Host: www.dropbox.com
Accept: */*
```

Verbose output from cmdline curl:

```
*   Trying 162.125.69.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.dropbox.com (162.125.69.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: businessCategory=Private Organization; jurisdictionCountryName=US; jurisdictionStateOrProvinceName=Delaware; serialNumber=4348296; C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=Dropbox, Inc; CN=www.dropbox.com
*  start date: Nov 14 00:00:00 2017 GMT
*  expire date: Feb 11 12:00:00 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.dropbox.com" matched cert's "www.dropbox.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x7fd8c4007a00)
> HEAD /s/0hvgw7nvbdnh13d/ColaClassic.zip HTTP/2
> Host: www.dropbox.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
```

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); //I` - yeah, nope, wishful thinking. `-I` means make a HEAD request, CURLOPT_HEADER means include the response headers in the output. You want `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'HEAD');` to properly translate that `-I`

Comment: @misorude even after I added `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` parameter, I still get text/html as Content-Type

Comment: You can get a “translation” of your cURL command to PHP here, https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ If it still doesn’t work with that - then I’d start by sending a request using both methods to a script of my own, that simply logs all request headers, and then check for significant differences.

Comment: Yes, I already tried. I removed `FOLLOWLOCATION` (set to false) and in php, I get http status code 200 and in cmd i get 301. How is this possible? Same link

Comment: Well _something_ about those two requests must be different somehow - hence my suggestion to start by logging what they actually look like.

Comment: did you try to add curl option `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);` ? @golobich and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`

Comment: I have updated my question. Yes, I have this two options present, but I do not believe . that I need to have binary transfer since I am only doing head request? However, from verbose output, I can see that PHP is requestion HTTP/1.1, from command line HTTP/2. Can this be the issue?

Comment: actually, I can't see proof that curl is actually following links ... Is this follow location set ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems dropbox is issuing a different response code depending on user agent — or rather lack thereof.  Your command line operation sends something like `curl/7.47.0` (or your version) while the php script sends an empty user agent.  Adding the user agent to your php request will get dropbox to respond appropriately with a `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` response and then your script will follow the location on as expected:

```
$ch = curl_init();
// emulates user agent from command line.
$user_agent = 'curl/' . curl_version()['version'];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.dropbox.com/s/0hvgw7nvbdnh13d/ColaClassic.zip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); //I
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); //without body
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); //L
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);

curl_exec($ch);
$content_type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
echo $content_type;
```

**UPDATE:** Oddly, I just tried a few other things, like emulating various browser useragent strings and it seems dropbox only seems to issue a redirect when presented with the `curl/X.X.X` useragent. **`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`**

Comment: Thank you for this! Yes, I was also experimenting with user agent parameter after you gave me this answer. It is also working with `curl/` as user agent. Bit if I add my browser user agent then it doesnt work. Maybe it works like this because if I go to that page with browser, then page will open and show me the content of zip file.